# image is not scrolling when both scrollview and image view are in storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift3, xcode8

I created a sample project using Xcode 8 with a storyboard having a scroll view and image view as subview of scrollview. image view's content mode is set to center. Scrollview doesn't scroll .

[![Here are the constraints in the story board:
scrollView][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPqu6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPqu6.png)

Here is the code

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageURL = "http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/cosmea_floral_bloom-wide.jpg"
}

var imageURL: String? {
    didSet {
        updateImage()
        scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
    }
}

func updateImage() {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOf: URL(string:imageURL! )!) {
        imageView.image = UIImage(data: data as Data)
        imageView.sizeToFit()
    }
}
```

}

However, when I create my imageView programmatically, scrollView works. What am I missing in the above code? code below works

```
import UIKit
```

class ImageViewController: UIViewController {

```
var image: UIImage? {
    get {
        return imageView.image
    }
    set {
        imageView.image = newValue
        imageView.sizeToFit()
    }
}

var imageUrl: URL? {
    didSet {
        image = nil
        fetchImage(url: imageUrl)
    }
}

func fetchImage(url: URL?) {
    let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)
    image = UIImage(data: data as! Data)!
}

var imageView = UIImageView()

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    imageUrl = ImageData.imageURL(for: ImageData.images["imageOne"]!)!
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    scrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size
}
```

}

Comment: What constraints did you add when you set it up in the storyboard?

Comment: I added a screenshot for the constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delete the align center X and align center Y constraints. These constraints are holding your image view in place and not allowing scrolling.

When you delete them you will likely get a constraints error. This is because at design time your layout is ambiguous. The image view's intrinsic size is based on the image, but you want to set your image at run time. To resolve this, you should select your image view, go to the size inspector, click on the intrinsic size drop down menu and set a placeholder size. The placeholder size will only be used at design time and be replaced at run time.